derivative of Logistic Regression with sigmoid func
I am having difficulty figuring out, why I get different answer from the professor. we are tasked with finding the deriative of the logistic regression cost function with the sigmoid function:
$$L(w│D)=−\frac{1}{m}∑[y_ilog(σ(w^Tx_i))+(1−y_i)log(1−σ(w^Tx_i))]$$
after some calculations I got to the solution:
$$−\frac{1}{m}∑[y_i−σ(w^Tx_i)]x_i$$
but the professor answer is
$$−\frac{1}{m}∑[σ(w^Tx_i)-y_i]x_i$$
its flipped...
I looked at many other calculations, some of them ended up like mine and some like the professor. additionally chatGPT says that both forms can be used "In the context of logistic regression, both forms are used in different contexts."
I dont understand how both forms could be interperted in a simmilar manner, since our goal is to minimize the cost function, every minus sign should be improtant.
I dont think my problem is with the calculations as I seen answers online for each form and my questiuon is more conceptual, but someone asked me to upload my work:


(1) please don’t re-post closed questions. Instead, edit the question so that it can be reopened. (2) use math typesetting instead of illegible images. You will be more likely to receive a helpful answer.
